# Why does Tag Manager not detect my dataLayer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

So I have a working dataLayer, except GTM doesn't detect it.

This is a screenshot of the dataLayer.

[image]

The first dataLayer in the picture is the one GTM detects and is working.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example it looks like you are pushing an array when you should be pushing an object - which itself may contain arrays, so if you push a key/value pair and make the array the value this should work.